# ROS create class that moves the turtlesim

Tags: c++, ros

I want to create a class that move the turtlesim node to the x,y location. However, when I check the rostopic /turtle1/cmd_vel, it does not show any Twist, and the turtlesim node does not move at all. I'm still getting the position of the turtle but since the turlte not moving then it just stuck in the while loop forever. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class PathFinding{
Private:
   turtlesim::Pose initLocation;
   turtlesim::Pose finalLocation;
   double distance_tolerance;
   ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub;
   ros::Subscriber pose_sub;
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
public:
   PathFinding(turtlesim::Pose goal, double d, ros::NodeHandle &n){
          finalLocation = goal;
          nh = n;
          distance_tolerance = d;
          cmd_vel_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/turtle1/cmd_vel", 10);
          pose_sub = nh.subscribe("/turtle1/pose", 1000, &PathFinding::poseCallBack,this);

   }

   double getDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2,double y2){
         return sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2) + pow((y1-y2),2));
   }

   void moveGoal(){
          geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;
          ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

          do{
                 vel_msg.linear.x = 1.5*getDistance(initLocation.x,initLocation.y,finalLocation.x,finalLocation.y);
                 vel_msg.linear.y = 0;
                 vel_msg.linear.z = 0;

                 vel_msg.angular.x = 0;
                 vel_msg.angular.y = 0;
                 vel_msg.angular.z = 4*(atan2(finalLocation.y-initLocation.y,finalLocation.x-initLocation.x) - initLocation.theta);

                 cmd_vel_pub.publish(vel_msg);

                 ros::spinOnce();
                 loop_rate.sleep();
          }


          while(getDistance(initLocation.x,initLocation.y,finalLocation.x,finalLocation.y) > distance_tolerance);

          vel_msg.linear.x = 0;
          vel_msg.angular.z = 0;

          cmd_vel_pub.publish(vel_msg);

}


    void poseCallBack(const turtlesim::Pose &p_msg){
        initLocation.x = p_msg.x;
        initLocation.y = p_msg.y;
        initLocation.theta = p_msg.theta;
    }
};
}
```

and this is how I use it:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ros::init(argc, argv, "turtleClassMoving");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    turtlesim::Pose goal;
    goal.x = 1;
    goal.y = 1;
    goal.theta = 0;

    PathFinding t(goal, 0.5, n);
    t.moveGoal();
    ros::spin();

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common error when passing a node handle to a class, as in your case, is to forget to pass the private node handle. So maybe your program is actually sending commands on a topic, but not the one you expect.

So, first of all check if any other cmd vel is sent with

rostopic list

If, as I expect, there is a similar name topic, with a different prefix, try modifying your main as

ros::NodeHandle n("~");